# Spring Kotlin : Bean fields are null at runtime despite being injected during instantiation

Tags: spring, kotlin, autowired, reactive, cglib

I am giving a try to Spring Kotlin support and I want to achieve the following simple DAO pattern inside a Spring Boot application (Using Spring reactive features, generated thanks to the Spring Initializr website) :

```
@Document
data class Person(val age: Int, val name: String)

abstract class AbstractDAO<T>(private val clazz: Class<T>, private val reactiveMongoTemplate: ReactiveMongoTemplate) {
    fun create(t: Mono<T>) = reactiveMongoTemplate.insert(t)
    fun findAll() = reactiveMongoTemplate.findAll(clazz)
}

@Repository
class GroupDAO(reactiveMongoTemplate: ReactiveMongoTemplate) : AbstractDAO<Group>(Group::class.java, reactiveMongoTemplate)

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/group")
class GroupController(val groupDao: GroupDAO) {

    @PostMapping("/create")
    fun create(@RequestBody group: Mono<Group>) = groupDao.create(group)

}
```

Here is the relevant stacktrace :

```
2018-10-02 10:07:51.294  INFO 19434 --- [-server-epoll-5] r.ipc.netty.tcp.BlockingNettyContext     : Started HttpServer on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0%0:8080
2018-10-02 10:07:51.294  INFO 19434 --- [           main] o.s.b.web.embedded.netty.NettyWebServer  : Netty started on port(s): 8080
2018-10-02 10:07:51.295 DEBUG 19434 --- [           main] s.b.w.r.c.StandardReactiveWebEnvironment : Adding PropertySource 'server.ports' with highest search precedence
2018-10-02 10:07:51.298  INFO 19434 --- [           main] fr.rs.reactive.ReactiveApplicationKt     : Started ReactiveApplicationKt in 7.284 seconds (JVM running for 8.072)
2018-10-02 10:08:06.655 ERROR 19434 --- [-server-epoll-7] .a.w.r.e.DefaultErrorWebExceptionHandler : Failed to handle request [POST http://localhost:8080/group/create]

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at fr.rs.reactive.dao.AbstractDAO.create(AbstractDAO.kt:7) ~[classes/:na]
    at fr.rs.reactive.web.GroupController.create(GroupController.kt:19) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:243) ~[spring-webflux-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.InvocableHandlerMethod.lambda$invoke$0(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-webflux-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
```

The ligne 7 in the AbstractDAO class is this one :

```
fun create(t: Mono<T>) = reactiveMongoTemplate.insert(t)
```

This code compiles and my application starts and runs, but the following behavior occurs and I get a NullPointerException when the insert or the findAll methods are actually called. Here are my observations :

- When I put a breakpoint on the class line of the AbstractDAO class, the reactiveMongoInstance is correctly injected -> not null
- When I put a breakpoint in a method annotated with @PostConstruct, the reactiveMongoInstance field is correctly initialized
- The GroupDAO instance Spring creates is correctly injected when given as a constructor parameter of another class (For instance a controller)
- When a method of the GroupDAO instance is called from the controller, the NullPointerException occurs : both clazz and reactiveMongoTemplate are null
- In the constructor and @PostConstruct method, the GroupDAO instance as shown by the debugger seems to be a "normal" one, whereas the one injected in the controller is a Spring enhanced one (CGLIB)

Do you have any idea as why the enhanced instance fields are null at runtime despite being correctly injected on startup ? Do you think it is related to my app being a "reactive" one ? Or is it related to Kotlin ? I had no problem implementing this pattern in non reactive Spring boot java based app.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: hmm seems like you are not autowiring the proper instances in your controller. Could you post how you are invoking the `insert` and `findAll` methods , as well as your exception stack trace

Comment: Thanks for your comment @AntJavaDev . I added the requested elements. I'll try the same code but in pure JAVA as soon as I get some time today, this will help us in telling if the problem comes from Kotlin or from this reactive Spring setup.

Comment: so indeed it looks like the injected `GroupDAO` is another instance , could you please double check it by printing the `GroupDAO` signature which you say its instantiated properly within the `@PostConstruct` and print the same for the instance while calling the controller method

Comment: Thanks again for your help @AntJavaDev . I didn't get any time tolook into the matter again today but I'll do when I get some free time, I'll let you know

Comment: Have you activated the spring plugin to make the classes open? If not, try making your GroupDAO open.

Comment: indeed as mentioned by @JBNizet , this might be your case , cause the `GroupDAO` does not specify any context keyword(didnt notice it from the first time) , so its by default `final`. The error thats been thrown, should be a different one , but give it a try. More info [here](https://dzone.com/articles/open-your-classes-and-methods-in-kotlin) and [here](https://blog.frankel.ch/open-your-classes-and-methods-in-kotlin/)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue like this with Kotlin and Spring. The solution was to make the bean class and the field open, like indicated in some of the comments here.

Please try:
`open class GroupController(open val groupDao: GroupDAO)`

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to address the clash between Kotlin's good stuff and Spring's magic is to use the Kotlin [allopen compiler plugin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/all-open-plugin.html) that makes classes and their properties open where necessary.

To configure this with Gradle, add add the following:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-allopen:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

apply plugin: "kotlin-spring" // instead of "kotlin-allopen"
```

And for Maven, use:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
    <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <jvmTarget>${jvmTarget}</jvmTarget>
        <compilerPlugins>
            <plugin>spring</plugin>
        </compilerPlugins>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <executions>
        ...
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

If using Jetbrains IDEA, then once your Gradle or Maven build has been refreshed, you'll find the following under
`Project settings -> Modules -> [some module] -> Kotlin`

[image: project settings under modules then kotlin compiler plugin]